# How to typecast values based on fieldtypes?

Tags: fields, typecast

How to typecast values based on field types?

I have a map of field Types and field Values(in Strings)? how to convert each field Values based on the field Types dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing it like this:

```
                   if(fieldType == 'currency' || fieldType == 'double' || fieldType == 'percent' || fieldType == 'decimal' )
                    {
                        updateObj.put(field, decimal.valueOf(value)); 
                    }
                    else if(fieldType == 'boolean')
                    {
                        updateObj.put(field, Boolean.valueOf(value)); 
                    }                   
                    else if(fieldType == 'date')
                    {
                        updateObj.put(field, date.valueOf(value)); 
                    }                
                    else
                    {
                        updateObj.put(field,value);
                    }
```

If anyone has better idea let me know?

Comment: date fields not working :( with the above code

Comment: **Date.parse(strVal)** is the method you want if the original type is String (e.g. when parsing a CSV) in the locale's standard date format

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.valueOf()
```

example

```
String number = '12';
Integer someInteger = Integer.valueOf(number);
```

And some method for date:

```
Date myDate = date.newinstance(1960, 2, 17);
```

I assume you iterate over object fields using for loop, I am right?
If so I think that you should implement some requiments, mayby something like this :

```
if(fieldType == 'Integer'){
 Sobejct.put(field name, Integer.valueOf(fieldValue));
}
```

But I still have problem with understanding why you need this?
If you want to have value or each object in my opinion it is always better to move this to code (if you can't set deflaut values of field)

Comment: It should be dynamic,the fields can be of any type so how can I convert it to particular type using valueOf?

Comment: Cant you try keep it in some map and as key use conversion type?
Or custom setting?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: What more concern me - can you explain why do you need such function?

Comment: I am storing certain field values in QuickAction so that I dont need to store default values in code. but the problem with QuickAction is that -- it stores all types of field values in the form of String.So I need to have a dynamic typecasting.